# Estimating noise variance

Tags: normal-distribution, white-noise

I want to know how can we estimate the noise variance from noisy observations. Lets say. I have a variable x that has mean u and variance $\sigma^2$. Now lets say I have 100 samples of this variables.

Now suppose I add 100 noise observations from a gaussian noise with mean 0 and variance 1 to the 100 samples of the variable x.

Now if I calculate the variance of x after adding noise, it is 2. So from these noisy samples how am I supposed to know that the noise variance added was just 1 and the variance of the original data was itself 1 as well.

Likewise in the case of multivariate is it possible to estimate the actual covariance matrix $\Sigma_x$ and the noise covariance matrix $\Sigma_n$

Is it possible at all?

Comment: @NickCox. I get a variance of 2 though. I just did a ~ N(0,1) and b ~ N(0,1). Generated 100 samples for each. Let c = a + b and var(c) = 2. By properties of variance. var(a+b_ = var(a)+var(b)+2cov(a,b). Since a and b are indepenent cov(a,b) = 0. var(a) = 1 and var(b) =1 so it is equal to 2

Comment: @NickCox. My question was if the original variable itself has some variance and the noise added has some variance. Then is it possible to separate the noise variance and the actual variance from the noisy observations? I assume we can get the nugget to estimate the noise variance. However, what's the solution in the case of multivariate x.

Comment: You have answered your main question, as I understand it. You stipulated adding noise of variance 1, so you can by the same token subtract that variance.